# Bootstrap Nav pills a:visited not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-selectors

[image]
  I am new to Bootstrap. I am using bootstrap Nav pills. I wanted to change tab color unvisited tab - yellow; already visited tab- red; current tab- green.

visited link doesn't changed to red. some one please help me

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    .nav-pills>li>a {
      background-color: yellow;
      color: white;
      border-radius: 0px;
    }

    .nav-pills>li>a:visited {
      background-color: red;
    }

    .nav-pills>li.active>a,
    .nav-pills>li.active>a:focus {
      background-color: green;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
      <li class="active">
        <a data-toggle="pill" href="#home">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu3">Menu 3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        home
      </div>
      <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
        menu 1
      </div>
      <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
        menu 2
      </div>
      <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
        menu 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Some one please help me fix bug in the code

Answer (score 0):

.nav-pills>li.active>a:not(:visited), .nav-pills>li.active>a:focus:not(:visited) { background-color: green; 
}

Try it like this with the :not(:visited) added

Comment: Ah sorry, it is because "li.active a" will always be more specific than "li a:visited". To have visited links always red you have to add the rule "li.active a:visited" so it will be more specific.